# How to correctly update progress bar in a GridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, mobile

I have a `GridView` with cells containing a book title and a download button. I want the download button to disappear and a progress bar to appear when that button is pressed. At the same time I start downloading a file and want to update the progress bar as I get updates from the download. Finally when the download is complete I want to hide the progress bar and show a *Read* button.

The way I've structured this myself is to create a custom Adapter, with the following getView method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final RelativeLayout card;
            if (convertView == null) {
                card = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.book_cover, null);
            } else {
                card = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
            }
            TextView bookName = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.textView_bookName);
            final MNBook currentBook = getItem(position);
            bookName.setText((String) currentBook.getTitle());
            final Button downloadBookButton = (Button) card.findViewById(R.id.button_download_book);
            final Button readBookButton = (Button) card.findViewById(R.id.button_read_book);
            final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) card.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_book_download);
            downloadBookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    downloadFile(currentBook, progressBar,
                            downloadBookButton, readBookButton);
                }
            });
            if (currentBook.isBooleanDownloaded()) {
                downloadBookButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                readBookButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return card;
        }
```

With the following `downloadFile` method:

```
private void downloadFile(MNBook book, final ProgressBar progressBar,
                              final Button downloadButton, final Button readButton) {
        final MNBook localBook = book;
        String fileName = book.getFileName();
        String url = book.getURL();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", url);
        intent.putExtra("file_name", fileName);
        intent.putExtra("receiver", new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
                super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
                if (resultCode == DownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
                    int progress = resultData.getInt("progress");
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    if (progress == 100) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        readButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        setDownloadedBookStatus(localBook);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        downloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        startService(intent);

    }
```

The problem I have with this approach is that the progress bar jumps to other cells. Basically, if I hit download on one book and scroll down, the progress appears in different book.

I want to know how I could fix this issue. It's okay for me if there is an alternate way to setup my code.

(Cross-posted on /r/androidquestions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're experienceing is in how Android handles views when you scroll. Say you have items A,B and C. If you start downloading on item A, you send in the references to the  views that item A is currently using to be displayed.
The problem though when you start scrolling and say item C is now displayed is that Android will reuse these views and these views are now used to display item C.

One way of doing this to store the progress of the download in the MSBook object. So when Android displays the item you fetch the percentage and you then fill the progress bar with that amount.

When the progress of the download increases you also need to tell Android to update the list ui so you see the new progress bar's value. This is done through notifyDataSetChanged(). (preferably with the position of the item as well to be more efficient, have a quick look in the documentation :) )

So something like this should get you started:

```
private void downloadFile(MNBook book) {
        final MNBook localBook = book;
        String fileName = book.getFileName();
        String url = book.getURL();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", url);
        intent.putExtra("file_name", fileName);
        intent.putExtra("receiver", new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
                super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
                if (resultCode == DownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
                    int progress = resultData.getInt("progress");
                    localBook.setProgress(progrss);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        startService(intent);
    }
```

Now when you call notifyDataSetChanged() Android will call getView() again and since you updated the progress you will handle all view related parts there.

So in getView you will now have the code related to this:

```
if (progress == 100) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    readButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setDownloadedBookStatus(localBook);
}
```

Hope that helps you out a bit.

Comment: As a result of calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` every time I update the progress I notice that I'm no longer able to trigger new downloads. If I try pressing the download button while another is currently downloading then I get no response. The app itself is still responsive when I am downloading something since I'm able to scroll freely. Do you know a way to fix this issue?

Comment: I think this is a another problem in itself and probably needs a new question with more background information to get a proper answer. A quick idea is that It looks like you're using a service in the background to download, you can only have one Service of a type running at the same time so if you're already downloading something and you don't handle queueing inside the Service this would fail. Again though, it's just a guess as I don't know the rest of the code.